# Retrieving a char from stdin

Tags: c, string, file, input, char

How would I get a char from stdin. For example if stdin was `push("blah")`, and I wanted to retrieve the 3rd char/byte which is 's', how would I go about doing that? I'm not sure if `fgetc()` or `getchar()` is involved, I want to try avoiding a loop, but is a loop the only way to iterate through it, can I not just retrieve it directly like a `getchar(3)` type of thing?

Comment: Which third byte is `'s'`? But you can do `getchar(); getchar(); int c = getch();` it's not worth having a loop.

Comment: the s in push("blah")

Comment: well im reading from stdin, so i want to read the push part as well

Comment: Are you going to want to check earlier bytes later? Or are you just looking to throw away an arbitrary number of bytes of input?

Answer (score 1):

When reading from `stdin`, you typically want to read a line at a time, then work with that.

So start by using `fgets` to read a line, then check the contents of what is read.

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
if ((strlen(line) > 2) && line[2] == 's') {
    printf("got s\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard input is not normally seekable, so the only reliable way to read it is sequentially, from the beginning.  There are any number of ways you could extract specifically the third `char` without looping:

```
int c1;
char c2;
char c3;
char buf[4];

// approach 1:
getchar(); getchar(); c1 = getchar();

// approach 2:
scanf("%*c%*c%c", &c2);

// approach 3:
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
c3 = buf[3];
```

Note that those are intended for individual use, not sequential use; they are presented together for ease of presentation.  Note also, importantly, that no error / EOF checks are performed in those examples.  In real code it is essential to test your function call results for error codes.  Thirdly, note that the first two examples discard the two initial characters.  There is no possibility of getting them back later.  If you want them, you'll need to keep track of them, as, for example, the third alternative allows.